# Using alias with 'using'

Tags: c#, using

I would like to define my own alias for complex type. I'm curious why the compiler does not recognize already imported types. For example:

Works:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using myCollection = System.Collections.Generic.List
                    <System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>>;
```

Error:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using myCollection = List<Dictionary<string, string>>;
```

Comment: @Claus Jørgensen: Aliasing with `using` is pretty close. You just need to repeat it in each file since there is no `#include`.

Comment: Yes, but what he explicit asks for is a typedef, not a alias to get a shorthand for a namespace. The difference is large, even C++ developers tend to abuse typedef for what it's not meant for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    using myCollection = List<Dictionary<string, string>>;
}
```

`using` directives can't refer to types imported in the same scope. The above example works, because the last `using` directive refers only to types imported in an outer scope.

Comment: +1 I knew using could do aliasing, but never thought of it aliasing a specific type like this, and the scoping is news as well. Good info!